# Sending Spotify Desktop App Keypresses with AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey, spotify

What element of the desktop app accepts keypresses? I am trying to write an AutoHotKey script to handle media keys with different apps wanting the keypress. Spotify will not accept play/pause key or space when sent to the default element in the SpotifyMainWindow class (eg `Media_Play_Pause::ControlSend, ,{Media_Play_Pause}, ahk_class SpotifyMainWindow`).